# Shift a number left in verilog and only retain upper bits

Tags: verilog, hardware, hdl, register-transfer-level

I have the following wires in verilog:

```
wire [15:0] mywire;
wire [7:0] mywire_shifted
wire [4:0] shiftamount;
```

I want to shift mywire left by some amount, but only retain the upper 8 bits:

```
assign mywire_shifted = (mywire << shiftamount) >> 8;
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Perhaps something like this:

```
assign {mywire_shifted,8'0} = mywire << shiftamount;
```

Comment: does `shiftamount` change, or is it a fixed value?

Comment: shiftamount changes value at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your first solution is clean. But you could also do

```
assign mywire_shifted = mywire[shiftamount+8 +: 8];
```

This says starting from the LSB (shiftamount+8) return the next MSB(higher) 8 bits.

Comment: And shiftamount can change? it changes at runtime

Comment: When you have `[index1 : index2]`, both values must be compile time constants (an expression of literals and parameters) to represent a fixed width. When you have `[index +: width]`,or  `[index -: width]` index can be a runtime expression, but width must still be a compile time constant.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I didn't know that.